# wrong gprof results with gcc -Ofast -pg

Tags: c, gcc, profiling, gprof

I'm seeing strange profiling results with `gcc -pg` and `gprof`.

I can't find a better/smaller way to reproduce so I'm linking the actual code where I'm seeing the issue.

I'm using the code [here](https://github.com/erjoalgo/tetris-c/tree/ai-perf-test), building gprof profiling results with `make prof`

I notice several errors, mainly:

1. A function `shape_stream_test` that should never even be called is shown as being called heavily by `ai_best_move_rec` and taking up 15% of total run time in self time
2. Other functions legitimately called by `ai_best_move_rec` like `grid_block_remove`, `grid_cpy`, `grid_new` don't even show up as children

Actual prof stats:

```
Flat profile:

Each sample counts as 0.01 seconds.
  %   cumulative   self              self     total           
 time   seconds   seconds    calls  ms/call  ms/call  name    
 53.92      4.00     4.00  4231936     0.00     0.00  grid_eval
 13.62      5.01     1.01  4467368     0.00     0.00  shape_stream_test
  6.88      5.52     0.51  4690742     0.00     0.00  grid_block_center_top
  6.07      5.97     0.45  4521016     0.00     0.00  grid_block_valid
  5.80      6.40     0.43  4467368     0.00     0.00  grid_block_add
  3.37      6.65     0.25  4467368     0.00     0.00  grid_block_drop
  2.02      6.80     0.15       35     4.29   209.20  ai_best_move_rec
  1.95      6.95     0.15   235469     0.00     0.00  grid_init
  1.75      7.08     0.13  9212461     0.00     0.00  block_extreme
  1.48      7.19     0.11  4467402     0.00     0.00  block_move
  0.94      7.26     0.07  1654899     0.00     0.00  block_get
  0.54      7.30     0.04                             block_crust_get
  0.40      7.33     0.03                             grid_block_set_color
  0.27      7.35     0.02  4467368     0.00     0.00  grid_block_remove
  0.27      7.37     0.02   235501     0.00     0.00  block_new
  0.27      7.39     0.02                             grid_block_intersects
  0.20      7.40     0.02   235469     0.00     0.00  grid_new
  0.13      7.41     0.01   235467     0.00     0.00  shape_stream_peek
  0.13      7.42     0.01                             drop_amount
  0.00      7.42     0.00      621     0.00     0.00  grid_clear_lines
  0.00      7.42     0.00      587     0.00     0.00  grid_cpy
  0.00      7.42     0.00       35     0.00     0.00  grid_print
  0.00      7.42     0.00       34     0.00     0.00  block_init
  0.00      7.42     0.00       34     0.00     0.00  block_print
  0.00      7.42     0.00       34     0.00     0.00  game_move_print
  0.00      7.42     0.00       34     0.00     0.00  grid_apply_moves
  0.00      7.42     0.00       34     0.00     0.00  shape_stream_pop
  0.00      7.42     0.00        7     0.00     0.00  shape_new
  0.00      7.42     0.00        1     0.00     0.00  shape_stream_new

 %         the percentage of the total running time of the
time       program used by this function.

cumulative a running sum of the number of seconds accounted
 seconds   for by this function and those listed above it.

 self      the number of seconds accounted for by this
seconds    function alone.  This is the major sort for this
           listing.

calls      the number of times this function was invoked, if
           this function is profiled, else blank.

 self      the average number of milliseconds spent in this
ms/call    function per call, if this function is profiled,
       else blank.

 total     the average number of milliseconds spent in this
ms/call    function and its descendents per call, if this 
       function is profiled, else blank.

name       the name of the function.  This is the minor sort
           for this listing. The index shows the location of
       the function in the gprof listing. If the index is
       in parenthesis it shows where it would appear in
       the gprof listing if it were to be printed.

Copyright (C) 2012-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Copying and distribution of this file, with or without modification,
are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
notice and this notice are preserved.

             Call graph (explanation follows)


granularity: each sample hit covers 2 byte(s) for 0.13% of 7.42 seconds

index % time    self  children    called     name
                                                 <spontaneous>
[1]     98.7    0.00    7.32                 ai_test [1]
                0.15    7.17      35/35          ai_best_move_rec [2]
                0.00    0.00      34/34          grid_apply_moves [21]
                0.00    0.00       2/235469      grid_new [9]
                0.00    0.00      35/35          grid_print [24]
                0.00    0.00      34/34          game_move_print [27]
                0.00    0.00      34/34          shape_stream_pop [28]
                0.00    0.00       1/1           shape_stream_new [30]
-----------------------------------------------
                              235432             ai_best_move_rec [2]
                0.15    7.17      35/35          ai_test [1]
[2]     98.7    0.15    7.17      35+235432  ai_best_move_rec [2]
                4.00    0.00 4231936/4231936     grid_eval [3]
                1.01    0.00 4467368/4467368     shape_stream_test [4]
                0.51    0.11 4690742/4690742     grid_block_center_top [5]
                0.45    0.09 4521016/4521016     grid_block_valid [6]
                0.43    0.00 4467368/4467368     grid_block_add [7]
                0.25    0.00 4467368/4467368     grid_block_drop [8]
                0.02    0.15  235467/235469      grid_new [9]
                0.11    0.00 4467368/4467402     block_move [12]
                0.02    0.00 4467368/4467368     grid_block_remove [16]
                0.02    0.00  235467/235501      block_new [17]
                0.01    0.00  235467/235467      shape_stream_peek [19]
                0.00    0.00     587/587         grid_cpy [23]
                0.00    0.00     587/621         grid_clear_lines [22]
                              235432             ai_best_move_rec [2]
-----------------------------------------------
                4.00    0.00 4231936/4231936     ai_best_move_rec [2]
[3]     53.9    4.00    0.00 4231936         grid_eval [3]
-----------------------------------------------
                1.01    0.00 4467368/4467368     ai_best_move_rec [2]
[4]     13.6    1.01    0.00 4467368         shape_stream_test [4]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.51    0.11 4690742/4690742     ai_best_move_rec [2]
[5]      8.4    0.51    0.11 4690742         grid_block_center_top [5]
                0.07    0.00 4690742/9212461     block_extreme [11]
                0.04    0.00 1056160/1654899     block_get [13]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.45    0.09 4521016/4521016     ai_best_move_rec [2]
[6]      7.3    0.45    0.09 4521016         grid_block_valid [6]
                0.06    0.00 4521016/9212461     block_extreme [11]
                0.03    0.00  598739/1654899     block_get [13]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.43    0.00 4467368/4467368     ai_best_move_rec [2]
[7]      5.8    0.43    0.00 4467368         grid_block_add [7]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.25    0.00 4467368/4467368     ai_best_move_rec [2]
[8]      3.4    0.25    0.00 4467368         grid_block_drop [8]
                0.00    0.00     635/9212461     block_extreme [11]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       2/235469      ai_test [1]
                0.02    0.15  235467/235469      ai_best_move_rec [2]
[9]      2.2    0.02    0.15  235469         grid_new [9]
                0.15    0.00  235469/235469      grid_init [10]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.15    0.00  235469/235469      grid_new [9]
[10]     2.0    0.15    0.00  235469         grid_init [10]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00      68/9212461     grid_apply_moves [21]
                0.00    0.00     635/9212461     grid_block_drop [8]
                0.06    0.00 4521016/9212461     grid_block_valid [6]
                0.07    0.00 4690742/9212461     grid_block_center_top [5]
[11]     1.8    0.13    0.00 9212461         block_extreme [11]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00      34/4467402     grid_apply_moves [21]
                0.11    0.00 4467368/4467402     ai_best_move_rec [2]
[12]     1.5    0.11    0.00 4467402         block_move [12]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.03    0.00  598739/1654899     grid_block_valid [6]
                0.04    0.00 1056160/1654899     grid_block_center_top [5]
[13]     0.9    0.07    0.00 1654899         block_get [13]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[14]     0.5    0.04    0.00                 block_crust_get [14]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[15]     0.4    0.03    0.00                 grid_block_set_color [15]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.02    0.00 4467368/4467368     ai_best_move_rec [2]
[16]     0.3    0.02    0.00 4467368         grid_block_remove [16]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00      34/235501      grid_apply_moves [21]
                0.02    0.00  235467/235501      ai_best_move_rec [2]
[17]     0.3    0.02    0.00  235501         block_new [17]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[18]     0.3    0.02    0.00                 grid_block_intersects [18]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.01    0.00  235467/235467      ai_best_move_rec [2]
[19]     0.1    0.01    0.00  235467         shape_stream_peek [19]
-----------------------------------------------
                                                 <spontaneous>
[20]     0.1    0.01    0.00                 drop_amount [20]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00      34/34          ai_test [1]
[21]     0.0    0.00    0.00      34         grid_apply_moves [21]
                0.00    0.00      34/235501      block_new [17]
                0.00    0.00      68/9212461     block_extreme [11]
                0.00    0.00      34/4467402     block_move [12]
                0.00    0.00      34/34          block_init [25]
                0.00    0.00      34/621         grid_clear_lines [22]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00      34/621         grid_apply_moves [21]
                0.00    0.00     587/621         ai_best_move_rec [2]
[22]     0.0    0.00    0.00     621         grid_clear_lines [22]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00     587/587         ai_best_move_rec [2]
[23]     0.0    0.00    0.00     587         grid_cpy [23]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00      35/35          ai_test [1]
[24]     0.0    0.00    0.00      35         grid_print [24]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00      34/34          grid_apply_moves [21]
[25]     0.0    0.00    0.00      34         block_init [25]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00      34/34          game_move_print [27]
[26]     0.0    0.00    0.00      34         block_print [26]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00      34/34          ai_test [1]
[27]     0.0    0.00    0.00      34         game_move_print [27]
                0.00    0.00      34/34          block_print [26]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00      34/34          ai_test [1]
[28]     0.0    0.00    0.00      34         shape_stream_pop [28]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       7/7           shapes_read [68]
[29]     0.0    0.00    0.00       7         shape_new [29]
-----------------------------------------------
                0.00    0.00       1/1           ai_test [1]
[30]     0.0    0.00    0.00       1         shape_stream_new [30]
-----------------------------------------------

 This table describes the call tree of the program, and was sorted by
 the total amount of time spent in each function and its children.

 Each entry in this table consists of several lines.  The line with the
 index number at the left hand margin lists the current function.
 The lines above it list the functions that called this function,
 and the lines below it list the functions this one called.
 This line lists:
     index  A unique number given to each element of the table.
        Index numbers are sorted numerically.
        The index number is printed next to every function name so
        it is easier to look up where the function is in the table.

     % time This is the percentage of the `total' time that was spent
        in this function and its children.  Note that due to
        different viewpoints, functions excluded by options, etc,
        these numbers will NOT add up to 100%.

     self   This is the total amount of time spent in this function.

     children   This is the total amount of time propagated into this
        function by its children.

     called This is the number of times the function was called.
        If the function called itself recursively, the number
        only includes non-recursive calls, and is followed by
        a `+' and the number of recursive calls.

     name   The name of the current function.  The index number is
        printed after it.  If the function is a member of a
        cycle, the cycle number is printed between the
        function's name and the index number.


 For the function's parents, the fields have the following meanings:

     self   This is the amount of time that was propagated directly
        from the function into this parent.

     children   This is the amount of time that was propagated from
        the function's children into this parent.

     called This is the number of times this parent called the
        function `/' the total number of times the function
        was called.  Recursive calls to the function are not
        included in the number after the `/'.

     name   This is the name of the parent.  The parent's index
        number is printed after it.  If the parent is a
        member of a cycle, the cycle number is printed between
        the name and the index number.

 If the parents of the function cannot be determined, the word
 `<spontaneous>' is printed in the `name' field, and all the other
 fields are blank.

 For the function's children, the fields have the following meanings:

     self   This is the amount of time that was propagated directly
        from the child into the function.

     children   This is the amount of time that was propagated from the
        child's children to the function.

     called This is the number of times the function called
        this child `/' the total number of times the child
        was called.  Recursive calls by the child are not
        listed in the number after the `/'.

     name   This is the name of the child.  The child's index
        number is printed after it.  If the child is a
        member of a cycle, the cycle number is printed
        between the name and the index number.

 If there are any cycles (circles) in the call graph, there is an
 entry for the cycle-as-a-whole.  This entry shows who called the
 cycle (as parents) and the members of the cycle (as children.)
 The `+' recursive calls entry shows the number of function calls that
 were internal to the cycle, and the calls entry for each member shows,
 for that member, how many times it was called from other members of
 the cycle.

Copyright (C) 2012-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.

Copying and distribution of this file, with or without modification,
are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
notice and this notice are preserved.

Index by function name

   [2] ai_best_move_rec       [21] grid_apply_moves        [3] grid_eval
  [14] block_crust_get         [7] grid_block_add         [10] grid_init
  [11] block_extreme           [5] grid_block_center_top   [9] grid_new
  [13] block_get               [8] grid_block_drop        [24] grid_print
  [25] block_init             [18] grid_block_intersects  [29] shape_new
  [12] block_move             [16] grid_block_remove      [30] shape_stream_new
  [17] block_new              [15] grid_block_set_color   [19] shape_stream_peek
  [26] block_print             [6] grid_block_valid       [28] shape_stream_pop
  [20] drop_amount            [22] grid_clear_lines        [4] shape_stream_test
  [27] game_move_print        [23] grid_cpy
```

[image: wrong call graph with -Ofast]
Later I discovered I was combining the -Ofast and -pg flags, and removing -Ofast fixes these issues above.

[image]

My questions are:

1. Are these two flags incompatible? I couldn't find any such warning in the docs
2. If they are not incompatible, is this a gcc bug?
3. How can I work around this to see profiling results that match the most aggressive optimizations so that I don't waste time optimizing the wrong code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want speed, right? `-Ofast` only matters at the bottom of the call stack. It can't fix things that only you can fix. It can only make them harder to find. First turn off the optimizer and fix the things you can fix. [*Here's an example of how some people do it.*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/927773/23771) When you've gone as far as possible with that, turn on the optimizer and let it do its magic.

Small Flame :) Plenty of people say it's a waste of time to profile unoptimized code, but they *never say why*.
They heard it in a lecture hall, read it on a blog, or from stackoverflow, from someone whose clear authority on the subject obviates the need to give a reason.

I think it's a case of wishful thinking: My code is basically perfect, so the only ways it could be speeded up are to run the compiler's optimizer. Then when the profiler shows no way to speed it up - it's obviously right and hurray for me!

Added in response to comments: Let me digress a little bit (sorry). I understand that one can go over the code carefully, invest effort in data representations, inline some functions, do other high-level optimizations, and measure speedups from doing so. Great.
But if your reason for each code change is looking at and just thinking about the code, then as educated as your thinking is, it is still a guess.
A guess may be right, but the question you should be asking is "What have I missed?" and "How do I find it?"

The method many people and I use is [*random pausing*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/378024/23771).
The only tool it requires is a debugger, like GDB or any IDE.
It differs from profiling in that it locates unnecessary computation *directly*, rather than taking measurements and counting on you to decipher them, filter out the noise, look at particular routines, and hunt inside them.
It tells you down to the particular lines of code, and particular data, what the program is doing and why it's doing it.
Then you can ask if there's a less wasteful way to do that, and chances are there is.
What it does *not* do is tell you the precise fraction of time - you only get a very coarse measurement. What it *does* do is identify the problem.
You might think you certainly can't depend on such an inaccurate method, and that's true if you only see the problem on *one* sample.
But if you see it on *more than one* sample, you know it's big, and the fewer overall samples you took to see it more than once, the bigger it is.
[*Here are the statistics behind it.*](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262)
And here's the kicker: this will find any problem any profiler will find, and more.

Then when you find and fix one problem, you can do it all again, because removal of one problem magnifies the remaining problems.
In this way you can "ladder" the speedups until you can't any more.
That's how you get maximal speed [*as in this example*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/302345/2429).
Then, by all means, use `-Ofast`.

Comment: I think by "things only you can fix" you're referring to higher level optimizations. But in this case, I'm interested in manually doing low-level optimizations. This is why without -Ofast I don't think I'm getting an accurate representation of what parts of the code are worth my attention. I'm also very interested in understanding why this unrelated, not-called function appears in the stats, whether the flags are incompatible or whether this is a bug.

Comment: @erjoalgo: Gosh, multiple points. First, even if gprof had no bugs, [*it has many problems*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1779343/23771), so people could wonder why you're bothering to wrestle with it. Second, if speed is your objective, why are high-level optimizations not worth your attention? Third, anything you could do to speed up low-level code is evident in unoptimized code. If the compiler optimizes some low-level code, that does not make things *you* could do any more evident (even if it *did* show all functions). If you want, I'll try to explain this in greater detail.

Comment: On this particular project, I did invest enough effort into the data representation and algorithms to minimize complexity. So I've already spent a lot of effort on high level optimizations, and I'd like to catch the low-hanging fruit. For example, I already gained significant speedup by manual inline of some computations, by moving away from a sorting library, etc.

Comment: I agree that "anything you could do to speed up low-level code is evident in unoptimized code", but I don't think the converse is true, the profiler on optimized code might claim function X is worth a lot of attention when it will really be optimized well and not worth attention. For example, `grid_block_add` in the unoptimized program's graph takes almost twice as much total program time as in the optimized version (7% vs 13%).

Comment: I'd like to accept your answer for the sake of moving on with this. Would you mind adding what you would use instead of gprof to profile aggressively optimized code?

Comment: I like the idea about random sampling, I haven't tried it but I will. But I suspect I will see a lot of samples for say, grid_eval (from the above example), which takes %50 of my program but I'm not interested in optimizing right now.

Comment: @erjoalgo: If you pause it 10 times, you can verify your suspicion if grid_eval appears on about 5-6 of the samples. Then look at the other samples. Everything you see, no matter how you describe it, if you see it on more than one sample, is costing you. If you see something improvable on one sample, that should raise your hopes, but if you see it twice, it is significant, guaranteed. What it costs follows a [*beta distribution.*](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/2719/1262)